# Google Cloud userproject access denied error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload a file from my web site (made with nodejs) to my Google Cloud Storage.

But i get this error:

`starting-account-67n988tuygj7@sonproje-1533259273248.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to yiginlabilgi/sefer.jpg.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up the right [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) for the bucket. Add service account `starting-account-67n988tuygj7@sonproje-1533259273248.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as member to the bucket `yiginlabilgi` with `Storage Object Creator` role.

Follow the [Adding a member to a bucket-level policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add) in order to achieve that.